# Cannot drag and drop using harmon.ie addin in Outlook

Tags: sharepoint-2010, outlook-addin, harmon.ie

I am a newbie here, and this is my first post here so please don't judge :)

I need help with outlook addin for sharepoint called "harmon.ie". We have been using it (with sharepoint 2010) for years, but suddenly it stopped working with drag and drop function. This only happens in one sharepoint site (where this addin is used mainly). When i drag and drop file to any of the folders in that site - nothing happens (list just refresh). Connections working fine, permissions are set up properly, even given "all rights" as i thought this was the problem. No avail. When I tried in other sites and folders - everything is working fine, files uploading and I am able to see it. 
The "harmon.ie" logs it shows one error:

*09:15:15,956 ERROR [eclipse-CLR] com.mainsoft.sharepoint.sidebar.SideBarViewPart - External tabs provider was not found*

Sharepoint logs doesn't show any bad behaviour comparing to logs when files are uploaded fine. I am not a big coder, just a beginner so any help would be gold worth!

Comment: This isn't really a programming problem. You might want to ask on [sharepoint.stackexchange.com](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: Thanks, will try.

Answer (score 0):

Please download our latest release from our web site (released yesterday)
We have fixed a similar issue.

----- Jean

Comment: Downloaded the newest version - still the same problem :( don't know where else to search for the problem. Maybe there are some older offline installers?

Answer (score 0):

Please list the exact version in use.

If this issue only occurs with a specific SharePoint site it means the problem stems from your server.
Do you reproduce on top of our demo SharePoint site at:
http://ravenwood-corp.com/sandbox   username:sandbox password: sandbox

Gather the communication information between client (harmon.ie) and SharePoint server – we usually rely on Fiddler network tracing tool http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/ Please download and install it. If your Sharepoint site uses HTTPS secure protocol – after installing Fiddler, please go under ‘Tools -> Fiddler Options’, select ‘HTTPS’ tab and enable the checkboxes (Capture HTTPS Traffic, Decrypt HTTPS Traffic, Ignore Server Certificate Errors).
If installed and configured successfully – restart Outlook, and reproduce the problem i.e. D&D inside the problematic SharePoint site. You should see requests being registered in fiddler. Once the trace log is generated, save it via File -> Save All Sessions… and send me the generated .saz file

---- jean